# SQL запрос выдает ошибку - unknown column "Количество"

Tags: mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдает ошибку, проблема в 7ой строке запроса
Я не могу понять почему
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы не понимаете текст ошибки или в чем конкретно Ваша проблема?

Comment: Верните текст пожалуйста. Только отформатируйте его

Comment: [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/191482)

Answer (score 1):

Вот как работают такие запросы:

1. база ищет строки соответсвующие условиям where
2. база группирует все найденные строки согласно group by
3. сгруппированные строки дополнительно фильтруются условиями having

Теперь посмотрите на свой запрос. Вы просите базу найти строки, сумма значений которых больше десяти. Это лишено смысла. Чтобы получить сумму вам надо сперва  что-то сложить.

То что вы хотите сделать, делается с помощью having. Having работает с результатом вашей группировки. Перенесите ваше условие из where в having и всё заработает.

Comment: спасибо большое! помогли разобраться с ошибкой, но я все равно не понял из-за чего ошибка, дело в том, что столбец amount имеет тип данных - int => Количество, которое создается на основе amount тоже должно иметь тип данных int, почему же это строка? в какой момент происходит конкатенация или что-то, что приводит значение к другому типу данных

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @IgorMakarov ваша ошибка была в том, что вы хотели сравнивать с суммой до того как что-то сложили. О типах данных речь не шла. Если у вас теперь новая проблема с типом данных, то это совсем другая история. Вероятно вы проверяете тип в результатах вашего клиента (например в php). Так как типы в бд часто не совпадают с типами в программе, которая оперирует результатами, то многие клиенты возвращают все результаты как строки.